# Make DIV Class Inactive On Load Until List Item Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help getting a portfolio working on my website.

Currently I have ALL the pictures (from each of four categories) show up on load. However, only the photos from the selected category show up when I click to activate that category.

I want to make it so when the site loads and before anything is clicked, either none of the photos load or only one specified category's photos load.

**so far I have this:**

```
            <ul class="simplefilter">
                <li class="active" data-filter="1"><p>BRIDAL</p></li>
                <li data-filter="2"><p>PHOTOSHOOT</p></li>
                <li data-filter="3"><p>LASHES</p></li>
                <li data-filter="4"><p>OTHER</p></li>
            </ul>
```

**followed by this:**

```
               <div class="filtr-container">

               <!-- bridal photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="img/portfolio/bridal/bridal_1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/portfolio/bridal/bridal_1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>


                <!-- end bridal photos -->


                <!-- photoshoot photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="2">
                        <a href="img/portfolio/photoshoot/photoshoot_1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/portfolio/photoshoot/photoshoot_1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                 <!-- end photoshoot photos -->


                 <!-- lashes photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="3">
                        <a href="img/portfolio/lashes/lashes_1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/portfolio/lashes/lashes_1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                  <!-- end lashes photos -->


                  <!-- other photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="4">
                        <a href="img/portfolio/other/other_1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/portfolio/other/other_1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                   <!-- end lashes photos -->
                   </div>
```

**and my Javascript looks like this:**

```
$(function(){
    'use-strict';

    $('.simplefilter li').load(function() {
    $('.filtr-container').removeClass('active');
    });

     // portfolio filter container
    $('.filtr-container').filterizr();

    // portfolio filter
    $('.simplefilter li').click(function() {
        $('.simplefilter li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    // portfolio image-popup
    $(".image-popup").magnificPopup({
        type: "image",
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: "mfp-fade"
    });

});
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'use-strict';` does NOT enable strict mode, there has to be a space instead of a dash (`'use strict';`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key seems to be hidden in `filterizr` plugin you use.

On initialization where `$('...').filterizer()` constructor is called, you should pass it filter arguments:

```
$('.filtr-container').filterizr('filter', '1');
```

Comment: Todor Simenov...thank you! That was so easy and it worked! My coding knowledge is very basic.I haven't really done much since I was in college over 10 years ago.

Comment: If it worked for you please select the answer, so other user who come in to this to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want the images to not load when the page is opened, i'd suggest doing something like this:

```js
function changeSrc(){
 document.getElementById("myPhoto").src = "https://image.freepik.com/psd-gratis/projeto-do-fundo-da-textura-de-madeira-branca_1022-75.jpg";
}
```

```css
#myPhoto {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="changeSrc()">
  <h3>
    Click to show image!
  </h3>
  <img src="" id="myPhoto">
</div>
```

What this does is that it sets the source of the image just when clicking where you want the user to click to show the image. It's pretty simple and i hope this helps you somewhat.